# Real-time web application on python

Tags: python, web-applications, real-time

I'd just done a small project with [Meteor framework](http://meteor.com/) for NodeJS and feel it very awesome. I think real-time web app will be the future for web app, especially for mobile web app.

Can you suggest an Meteor alternative framework for Python?

Thanks,

Comment: oh, stackoverflow is almost real-time.

Comment: [Real-Time-Web-App-Stack-with-Python-Tornado](https://github.com/nellessen/Real-Time-Web-App-Stack-with-Python-Tornado)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Orbited with Twisted - http://www.clemesha.org/blog/realtime-web-apps-python-django-orbited-twisted/

Alternatively there's Django Socket JS with Tornado - https://github.com/peterbe/django-sockjs-tornado